# Windows failed to install flask-manager

Tags: python, powershell, flask

when I using PowerShell to run

```
pip install flask-manager
```

command, I received this error message:

```
Collecting flask-manager
  Using cached flask-manager-0.0.1a0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-g4lyg9vt\flask-manager\setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        with open(path.join(here, 'DESCRIPTION.rst'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
      File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\codecs.py", line 895, in open
        file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Gabriel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-g4lyg9vt\\flask-manager\\DESCRIPTION.rst'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-g4lyg9vt\flask-manager\
```

I've searched many related solution, some say to run command

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

or

```
easy_install -U setuptools
```

but it still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flask-manager` is alpha software, meaning it is in a ver early state of development. You should not expect alpha software to work 100%ly.

In this case the `setup.py` references a file `DESCRIPTION.rst` which is not included in the distribution archive. Also the instructions on the website how to install (`pip install https://github.com/hellupline/flask-manager.git`) are not working.

If you really want to try `flask manager`, you can check it out from git hub and copy or symlink the `flask_manager` subfolder into your `PYTHONPATH`.

We aware that alpha software ist not considered to be production ready.

Comment: This question was asked two years ago and flask-manager still has this problem. Not sure this can be considered an alpha issue any longer.

Comment: Since my answer there has been no new relaese. It is still the untouched alpha and I can not encourage anybody to use it in production.